# Delete wildcard in perl

Tags: perl, wildcard

I am a new to Perl, but I thought the following should work. I have the following snippet of a larger perl script

```
@mylist = ("${my_dir}AA_???_???.DAT", "${my_dir}AA???.DAT");

foreach my $list (@mylist) {
    if (-e $list) {
        system ("cp ${list} ${my_other_dir}");
    }
}
```

The above snippet is not able to find those wildcards, with `AA_???_???.DAT` but it does able to find the file name with the wildcard `AA???.DAT`

I have tried also deleting the files `AA??_???.DAT` as

```
unlink(glob(${my_dir}AA_???_???.DAT"))
```

but the script just hangs up.  But it is able to delete files match `AA???.DAT` using:

```
unlink(glob("${my_dir}AA???.DAT))
```

What could be the reasons?

Comment: You should always have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your Perl scripts, they really help you out with errors.

Comment: Thank you. I have taken note of it.!!!

Comment: Is my answer any use Yacob?

Answer (score 3):

`-e $list` checks for the existence of files, so return false for both `AA_???_???.DAT` or `AA???.DAT` (unless you actually have file named exactly that). It's not true that one works and he other one doesn't.

It's also not true that `unlink(glob(${my_dir}AA_???_???.DAT"))` hangs. For starters, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: foreach my $list (@mylist) {
        system ("cp ${list} ${my_other_dir}");
    }
This simply hangs up. Any comments please!!

Comment: What specifically is hanging? How did you determine this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `opendir` and `readdir` built-in functions (modified from the documentation example):

```
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";
@mylist = grep { /^(.AA_..._...\.DAT|AA...\.DAT)$/ && -f "$some_dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
```

Then you can plug in your original code:

```
foreach my $list (@mylist) {
    if (-e $list) {
        system ("cp $some_dir/${list} ${my_other_dir}/");
    }
}
```

For directory recursive file operations I really like to use the File::Find CPAN module. 
This will traverse through sub directories passing each file to a specified subroutine
to process that file. As an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @dirs='/path/to/dir';
my $my_other_dir='/path/to/otherdir';

find(&process_files, @dirs);

sub process_files {
    my($file) = $_;
    my($fullpath) = $File::Find::name;

    return if($file !~ /^AA_..._...\.DAT$/ and
        $file !~ /^AA...\.DAT$/);

    system ("cp $fullpath $my_other_dir/");
}
```

Comment: I would have written the pattern match in your [`grep`](http://p3rl.org/grep) as `/\A AA(?:_..._)?...[.]DAT \z/x`.

Comment: Hi Drav, When I tired to run your recursive file operations using File::Find module, I got the following error:Use of uninitialized value $file in pattern match (m//) at wildcard.pl line 55.
Use of uninitialized value $file in pattern match (m//) at wildcard.pl line 55.
no &wanted subroutine given at /usr/share/perl/5.14/File/Find.pm line 1064. Line 55 of refers to "return if ......."

Comment: not been logged in for a while, I'll take a quick look and get back to you.